# Как сделать "гамбургер-меню"

Tags: html, css, responsive

Доброго времени суток! Пытаюсь научиться делать гамбургер-меню, да не получается.

Помогите советом как сделать эту конструкцию рабочей на мобильных устройствах? Чтобы при `@media 600px` меню и ссылки на сети скрывались под кнопкой и становились рядом с логотипом. Заранее спасибо!

```css
.menu {
 width: 90%;
 height: 100px;
 background-color: #fff;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 align-items: center;
 padding-left: 5%;
 padding-right: 5%;
}

.menu__category li {
 display: inline;
 padding: 20px;
}

.menu__category a {
 padding-bottom: 36px;
 transition: all 0.2s ease;
 color: black;
}

.menu__category a:hover {
 border-bottom: 6px solid #ec4e4e;
 color: #ec4e4e;
}

.menu__social i {
 padding: 10px;
 transition: color 0.2s ease;
 font-size: 18px;
}

.menu__social i:hover {
 color: #ec4e4e;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
 <div class="menu__logo">
  <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo">
 </div>
 <div class="menu__category">
  <ul>
   <li>
    <a href="#">Home</a> 
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="menu__social">
  <i class="fa fa-vk" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) Добавить после menu__logo

```
<a href="#" class="mobile_menu_click">Бургер</a>
```

2) Подключить jquery

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```

3) В CSS добавить:

```
    .mobile_menu_click{
        display: none;
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 600px){
    .menu__category{
            display: none;
    }
    .mobile_menu_click{
        display: block;
    }
    .menu__category li {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

4) Добавить короткий JS код:

```
  <script>
    $('.mobile_menu_click').click(function(){
       $('.menu__category').fadeToggle();
    });
  </script>
```

Что до самой иконки "гамбургера", то в сети полно готовых решений.
Все остальное - это дело css

Answer (score 1):

И лучше вынести .menu__logo за пределы .menu (поставить перед)

```
<div class="menu__logo">
   <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo">
</div>

<a href="#" class="mobile_menu_click">Бургер</a>

 <div class="menu">
    <div class="menu__category">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Home</a> 
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="menu__social">
        <i class="fa fa-vk" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Так проще элементы стилизовать будет.

Comment: В примере используется БЭМ, если вынести `.menu__logo` за пределы `.menu`, то структура будет нарушена.