# Не отображается гамбургер меню на css (checkbox)

Tags: css, checkbox, menu, transform

**Меню** постоянно скрыто (`transform: translateY(-100%); opasity: 0;`), при нажатии должно выезжать сверху (`transform: translateY(0%); opasity: 1;`). Как его **отобразить** с помощью комбинаций селекторов **checkbox:checked**?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #222;
  background: #de3c3c;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
nav {
  color: #fff;
}
nav ul.navbar-wrapper {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #ea506e;
  width: 100%;
  height: 650px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-100%);
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
  transition: all .5s;
  opacity: 0;
}
nav ul li.nav-item {
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-align-self: center;
  -ms-flex-item-align: center;
  align-self: center;
}
nav ul li.nav-item a {
  display: block;
  color: #ffe7ec;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  line-height: 1.6;
}
nav ul li.nav-item a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

nav .hamburger {
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
nav label[for="hamburger"] {
  position: fixed;
  right: 25px;
  top: 20px;
  z-index: 3;
  height: 40px;
  width: 35px;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
}
/***********************************ПРОБЛЕМА**/
nav input.hamburger:checked + ul {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0%);
  transform: translateY(0%);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Big Menu</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" class="style">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://opensource.keycdn.com/fontawesome/4.7.0/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-dNpIIXE8U05kAbPhy3G1cz+yZmTzA6CY8Vg/u2L9xRnHjJiAK76m2BIEaSEV+/aU" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <ul class="navbar-wrapper">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>&#32;Home</a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-desktop" aria-hidden="true"></i>&#32;Articles</a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane" aria-hidden="true"></i>&#32;Drop me a line</a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i>&#32;Follow me</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <input type="checkbox" id="hamburger" class="hamburger"></input>
    <label for="hamburger"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </label>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать "гамбургер-меню"](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/613635/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b3%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b1%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b3%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8e)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сделайте класс для открытого меню, например, `.active`

```
nav ul.navbar-wrapper.active {
  opacity:1;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0);
  transform: translateY(0);
}
```

И добавляйте этот класс при нажатии на `#hamburger` (для jQuery):

```
$('#hamburger').click(function(){
 $('nav ul.navbar-wrapper').toggleClass('active')
})
```

```js
$('#hamburger').click(function(){
   $('nav ul.navbar-wrapper').toggleClass('active')
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #222;
  background: #de3c3c;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
nav {
  color: #fff;
}
nav ul.navbar-wrapper {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #ea506e;
  width: 100%;
  height: 650px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-100%);
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
  transition: all .5s;
  opacity: 0;
}
nav ul.navbar-wrapper.active {
  opacity:1;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0);
  transform: translateY(0);
}

nav ul li.nav-item {
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-align-self: center;
  -ms-flex-item-align: center;
  align-self: center;
}
nav ul li.nav-item a {
  display: block;
  color: #ffe7ec;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  line-height: 1.6;
}
nav ul li.nav-item a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
/***********************************ПРОБЛЕМА**/

nav .hamburger {
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
nav label[for="hamburger"] {
  position: fixed;
  right: 25px;
  top: 20px;
  z-index: 3;
  height: 40px;
  width: 35px;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
}
nav input.hamburger:checked + ul {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0%);
  transform: translateY(0%);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Big Menu</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" class="style">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://opensource.keycdn.com/fontawesome/4.7.0/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-dNpIIXE8U05kAbPhy3G1cz+yZmTzA6CY8Vg/u2L9xRnHjJiAK76m2BIEaSEV+/aU" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <ul class="navbar-wrapper">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>&#32;Home</a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-desktop" aria-hidden="true"></i>&#32;Articles</a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane" aria-hidden="true"></i>&#32;Drop me a line</a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i>&#32;Follow me</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <input type="checkbox" id="hamburger" class="hamburger">
    <label for="hamburger"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </label>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```